# Payara 5/6 and SpringFramework

Tags: spring, eclipselink, payara

I've come to the conclusion that the Spring Web MVC is not compatible with Payara 5 and 6. I have an application that uses Glassfish 3, Spring Web MVC, and EclipseLink JPA. I intend to upgrade the code to Java 17 and Jakarta EE. In the sake of kindness, it hasn't gone well. In all my efforts, it's been Spring's Web MVC that is causing the problems. Spring charges for support and that's not a viable option for me. Before I scrap it's use, let's pick your brain.

If anyone has implemented Spring Web MVC successfully with Payara 5 and/or 6, please share how you made it work.

My first step was to try Payara 6 for Jakarta EE. After creating a VERY small Hello World web app, I included Spring Web MVC jar and did the minimum to activate it's Dispatcher Servlet. I was never able to overcome the error CDI is not available.

Secondly, I backed off to Payara 5. In that attempt, it tries to instantiate a JPA EAO Bean that the app will use in all it's controllers to access the app's DB. The error here appears to be when it attempts to use FasterXML to read the persistence.xml file. That part of the app works fine when I create the EAO object with JUnit.

Rather than providing all the gory details, reviewing the artifacts from a successfully implemented app with help me tremendously.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So after weeks of beating my head against a wall trying all kinds of things to get it working, I wrote to one of the SpringFramework developers, Juergen Hoeller. Here's his response....

> Sorry to hear that there is so much trouble on Payara still. We also
> have corresponding reports on GitHub:
> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29718
> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29743
> Unfortunately neither of the two is an actual problem to be solved on
> Spring's own side, as far as I can see.
>
> With the CDI issue, it's Payara's CDI implementation not being able to
> parse Java 17's new record types. Also, I wonder why Payara needs to
> parse every single deployed class file if you are not actually using
> CDI. It might be possible to turn that off, but at the very least,
> Payara should defensively handle "unknown" types.
>
> With the Hibernate issue, it's a problem with Hibernate 6 initializing
> its Jackson configuration on Payara. There does not seem to be a StAX
> provider available, and Hibernate insists on one being present for
> Jackson.
>
> Overall, this needs to be taken to Payara and Hibernate, we are not
> aware of anything Spring can do better. Feel free to add further
> comments to the GitHub issues in case there is anything we can do from
> our side! Even if our focus is on Tomcat/Jetty these days, we of
> course want Spring 6 to work fine on Payara as well.
>
> Thanks for your efforts to try to make this work,
>
> Juergen

So now, how do we get the attention of Oracle's Glassfish developers and Payara's developers to get this resolved???? In the meantime, I think I'll have to install Tomcat or some other free webserver. Thanks, Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

This was reported against Hibernate before, but Glassfish/Payara simply have a broken classpath config. Also see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15556

Maybe try using [Wildfly](https://www.wildfly.org/), which is also free ;)